# QLabel takes complete space

Tags: c++, qt, space, qlabel

I have a QWidget which contains a QVBoxLayout and that layout contains a QLabel and QToolButtons. My problem is, that the QLabel takes all the space. The only solution I found is to set maximumHeight to the QLabel, but if I do that, the Qt::AlignTop doesn't work anymore.

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget window_main;

    QWidget *widget_steps = new QWidget(&window_main);
    widget_steps->setFixedWidth(75);
    widget_steps->move(QPoint(0, 0));
    widget_steps->setStyleSheet("background-color: red;");

    QVBoxLayout *layout_steps = new QVBoxLayout(widget_steps);
    layout_steps->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    layout_steps->setSpacing(0);

    QLabel *label_steps_start = new QLabel("steps:");
    label_steps_start->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop);
    label_steps_start->setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;");
    layout_steps->addWidget(label_steps_start);

    QToolButton *tbutton_step1 = new QToolButton();
    layout_steps->addWidget(tbutton_step1);

    QToolButton *tbutton_step2 = new QToolButton();
    layout_steps->addWidget(tbutton_step2);

    QToolButton *tbutton_step3 = new QToolButton();
    layout_steps->addWidget(tbutton_step3);


    window_main.showMaximized();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Here a picture that shows how much space the QLable takes(the blue space):
[image: QLabel_space]

So please help to minimize the space the QLable takes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the tool buttons have a fixed size, and therefore when resizing, the label is the only type that can grow: Therefore:
After adding the label, add stretch to the layout:

```
layout_steps->addWidget(label_steps_start);
layout_steps->addStretch();
```

Modified code - adds stretch at the bottom. Label size remains fixed, and buttons remain under it. I've removed the whole main window around the outside for the sake of testing.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget *widget_steps = new QWidget;
    widget_steps->setFixedWidth(75);
    widget_steps->move(QPoint(0, 0));
    widget_steps->setStyleSheet("background-color: red;");

    QVBoxLayout *layout_steps = new QVBoxLayout(widget_steps);
    layout_steps->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    layout_steps->setSpacing(0);

    QLabel *label_steps_start = new QLabel("steps:");
    label_steps_start->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop);
    label_steps_start->setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;");
    layout_steps->addWidget(label_steps_start);
    //--- Removed.... layout_steps->addStretch();

    QToolButton *tbutton_step1 = new QToolButton();
    layout_steps->addWidget(tbutton_step1);

    QToolButton *tbutton_step2 = new QToolButton();
    layout_steps->addWidget(tbutton_step2);

    QToolButton *tbutton_step3 = new QToolButton();
    layout_steps->addWidget(tbutton_step3);
    layout_steps->addStretch(); //<----- Added!
    widget_steps->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Nice, that works so far, but now the buttons stay at the bottom, how can I change the align of the buttons (there is no setAlign-function)?

Comment: When you are adding them, the third parameter is the alignment as indicated in my reply. Are you sure you fully checked my reply with the mods, btw?

Comment: Add some stretch after the last button.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do is to set the stretch factor for that particular widget inside the QVBoxLayout. You can find the documentation for that in [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qboxlayout.html#addWidget).

Basically, when you add a widget you can set that, for instance:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QToolButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget window_main;

    QWidget *widget_steps = new QWidget(&window_main);
    widget_steps->setFixedWidth(75);
    widget_steps->move(QPoint(0, 0));
    widget_steps->setStyleSheet("background-color: red;");

    QVBoxLayout *layout_steps = new QVBoxLayout(widget_steps);
    layout_steps->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    layout_steps->setSpacing(0);

    QLabel *label_steps_start = new QLabel("steps:");
    label_steps_start->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop);
    label_steps_start->setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;");
    layout_steps->addWidget(label_steps_start, 3, Qt::AlignTop);
    layout_steps->addStretch();

    QToolButton *tbutton_step1 = new QToolButton();
    layout_steps->addWidget(tbutton_step1, 1);

    QToolButton *tbutton_step2 = new QToolButton();
    layout_steps->addWidget(tbutton_step2, 1);

    QToolButton *tbutton_step3 = new QToolButton();
    layout_steps->addWidget(tbutton_step3, 1);


    window_main.showMaximized();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: that didn't help for me. I tried "layout_steps->setStretchFactor(label_steps_start, -1);" as well as "layout_steps->setStretchFactor(label_steps_start, 0);". Nothing changed...

Comment: Not even with aligntop?

Comment: I just added the strechFactor to the addWidget-function as you showed and let the other code unchanged -> nothing happened

Comment: @user1655806: IF this answer helped you, please modify the correct answer for the people in the future checking this thread, or say thank you to the other reply otherwise. :)